# Exception has occurred: TypeError start() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given in multithreading python

Tags: python, multithreading, artificial-intelligence

i created the class webviewThread in which i have created the run function in which i am passing 2 arguments "self, openWhat"  but it gives error on runtime. here is my code

```
class webviewThread(Thread):
    def run(self,openWhat):

        if openWhat=="facebook":
            webview.create_window('Facebook', 'http://www.fb.com')
            webview.start()

        elif openWhat=="youtube":
            webview.create_window('Facebook', 'http://www.youtube.com')
            webview.start()

webObj=webviewThread()

def openfacebook():
    webObj.start("facebook")
```

i am passing the value of argument but it gives error

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Use webObj.start() instead of webviewThread.start()

Comment: Your method is named `run` but you're calling `start`.

Comment: See my answer below. It doesn't look like you actually expose a `start()` method. You need to call `.run("facebook")` on the instance instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
webObj=webviewThread()
```

You are creating a new *instance* of the `webviewThread` class. When you call methods on that instance (like `start()`) the `self` argument (which references the instance itself) will automatically be passed to the method as its first argument.

However, if you call a method on the class object itself, as you are doing here:

```
webviewThread.start()
```

`self` will not be passed, as your error indicates. Instead, you need to call the method on the instance of `webviewThread` that you created:

```
webObj.start()
```

From your code example though I don't see that the `webviewThread` class has a `start()` method, so you may want to call `webObj.run()`

Here are some resources that explain Python classes and `self`.

- [Self in Python class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/)
- [The self variable in python explained](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)
- [Python classes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#classes)

## Update:

With regards to the error listed in your updated post title: `TypeError start() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`, this is occurring because you are calling `start()` on your instance, and passing the `"facebook"` argument. Since you have not overridden the `start()` method of the superclass `Thread`, you will be calling `Thread`'s `start()` method, which only takes a single argument: `self` (you are passing `self`, which happens automatically when you call the method on an instance, and `"facebook"` which you are passing explicitly).

Comment: thanks for answering, but can you check my problem again because i edited  question 2 minutes ago

Comment: Did you see my suggestion about using `run()` instead of `start()`?

Comment: That is a separate issue that may require a second post. However, your original error is caused by calling the start method with an extra argument. See my update for a detailed explanation.